# Key Navigation with Javascript

Tags: javascript, navigation, key

Please Help! I have spent a week to complete this game and this is the final huddle i have been stuck with for a couple of days now. I know some techy out there would probably take a glance and flick something in place. But I'm not very sophisticated with javascript and therefore need some help.

```
 $(document).keydown(function(e){
    // left arrow
    if (e.keyCode == 37 && currentCell > 0) { 
       currentCell--;
       ChangeCurrentCell();
       return false;
    }
    // up arrow
    if (e.keyCode == 38 && currentRow > 0) { 
       currentRow--;
       ChangeCurrentCell();
       return false;
    }
    // right arrow
    if (e.keyCode == 39 && currentCell < MAX_CELL) { 
       currentCell++;
       ChangeCurrentCell();
       return false;
    }
    //down arrow
    if (e.keyCode == 40 && currentRow < MAX_ROW) { 
       currentRow++;
       ChangeCurrentCell();
       return false;
    }
    // enter key
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {

    }
     });


 function ChangeCurrentCell()
 {

    document.getElementById(Boxes[currentRow + currentCell]).focus();
    SimulateMouseOver(document.getElementById(Boxes[currentRow + currentCell]));

 }


 // function will trigger event of selecting current focus.
 function selectElement()
 {

 }

 $(document).ready(function(){

    loadDivs()

// will give initial focus to top left element paving way for key navigation
   ChangeCurrentCell();
  // above gives first element in Boxes the focus when loading.
```

The div element will not focus despite getting it and calling the focus method, i have tried to trigger mousehover on the element with no luck. Please assist me, i put my masters thesis aside despite already being on a tight schedule to do this game which is a requirement for a job position. I have done whole the whole game logic and it all works well, if i send the code in as it is it will definitely be discarded because it doesnt meet the key navigation requirement ... i am desperate i will even pay if i need to -frustrated Student

Comment: Check `e.which` on event for arrows `37,38,39,40`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [this](http://www.lucaballore.com/ColourMemory/)

It's my solution for a test, maybe the same...maybe can help you :) If it is, please use it as a hint and don't copy all my code :D

Regards,

L.

Comment: thanks mate... but i already passed it up yesterday... I'm not expecting a call tho... good luck! and thanks again for assisting

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the `document.keydown` event to capture key strokes. Then you can use `event.which` (normalized by jQuery) to determine which key was pressed.

```
$(document).on("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.which === 37) {
        //code for left arrow
    } else if (event.which === 38) {
        //code for up arrow
    } else if (event.which === 39) {
        //code for right arrow
    } else if (event.which === 40) {
        //code for down arrow
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

I just noticed you didn't tag your question with jQuery. To use native JS you'll have to change how you bind to the `document.keydown` event and how you determine the key that was pressed (different browser implementations store the info under different indexes of the `event` object).

Comment: Please anyone! assist me please

Answer (score 0):

to make it more convenient () not necessary:

```
`var LEFT = 37, UP = 38, RIGHT = 39, DOWN = 40, SPACE = 32;`
```

then bind to keydown, keypress doesn't catch arrow keys
and do something like this:

```
$(document).bind("keydown", function (e){
    var which = e.which;
    var navigationKeyWasPressed = which !== undefined && which >= 39 && which <= 40; 
    //do nothing if no significant key was pressed
    if (!navigationKeyWasPressed ) {
        return;
    }
    if ($(".selectedWithKey").length === 1){
        switch (which) {
            case LEFT:
                //...
                break;
            case UP:
                //...
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                //...
                break;
            case DOWN:
                //...
                break;
            case SPACE:
                //turn card
                break;
            default: //non arrow pressed
            //...
        }
    } else {
        // if no card is selected, select one to start arrow navigation
        $(".sponsor:first").addClass("selectedWithKey")
    }
});
```